# Importing Too Many Fields in Custom Edit Form Using LWC

Tags: javascript, lightning-web-components, html

I have a custom edit form that includes too many fields. The current one does not look neat and there's a possibility to add more fields in the future.

Is there any way for me to be able to access field values in edit form without importing all fields one by one?

Below are the codes I am working on:

**HTML FILE**

```
<template>
    <lightning-card title="ContactEditForm" icon-name="standard:contact">
        <div class="slds-var-m-around_medium">
            <lightning-record-edit-form object-api-name={objectApiName} record-id={recordId}>
                <lightning-messages></lightning-messages>
                <lightning-input-field
                    field-name={lastNameField}>
                </lightning-input-field>
                <lightning-input-field
                    field-name={firstNameField}>
                </lightning-input-field>
                <lightning-input-field
                    field-name={accountField}>
                </lightning-input-field>
                <lightning-input-field
                    field-name={titleField}>
                </lightning-input-field>
                <lightning-input-field
                    field-name={phoneField}>
                </lightning-input-field>
                <lightning-input-field
                    field-name={emailField}>
                </lightning-input-field>
                <lightning-input-field
                    field-name={custom1Field}>
                </lightning-input-field>
                <lightning-input-field
                    field-name={custom2Field}>
                </lightning-input-field>
                <lightning-input-field
                    field-name={custom3Field}>
                </lightning-input-field>
                <lightning-input-field
                    field-name={custom4Field}>
                </lightning-input-field>
                <lightning-input-field
                    field-name={custom5Field}>
                </lightning-input-field>
                <lightning-input-field
                    field-name={custom6Field}>
                </lightning-input-field>
                <lightning-input-field
                    field-name={custom7Field}>
                </lightning-input-field>
                <lightning-input-field
                    field-name={custom8Field}>
                </lightning-input-field>
                <lightning-input-field
                    field-name={custom9Field}>
                </lightning-input-field>
                <lightning-input-field
                    field-name={custom10Field}>
                </lightning-input-field>
                <lightning-input-field
                    field-name={custom11Field}>
                </lightning-input-field>
                <lightning-input-field
                    field-name={custom12Field}>
                </lightning-input-field>
                <lightning-input-field
                    field-name={custom13Field}>
                </lightning-input-field>
                <lightning-input-field
                    field-name={custom14Field}>
                </lightning-input-field>
                <lightning-input-field
                    field-name={custom15Field}>
                </lightning-input-field>
                <div class="slds-var-m-top_medium">
                    <lightning-button
                        variant="brand"
                        type="submit"
                        name="save"
                        label="Save">
                    </lightning-button>
                </div>
            </lightning-record-edit-form>
        </div>
    </lightning-card>
</template>
```

**JS FILE**

```
import { LightningElement, api } from 'lwc';

import LASTNAME_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/Contact.LastName';
import FIRSTNAME_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/Contact.FirstName';
import ACCOUNT_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/Contact.AccountId';
import TITLE_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/Contact.Title';
import PHONE_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/Contact.Phone';
import EMAIL_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/Contact.Email';
import CUSTOMFIELD1_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/Contact.CustomField1__c';
import CUSTOMFIELD2_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/Contact.CustomField2__c';
import CUSTOMFIELD3_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/Contact.CustomField3__c';
import CUSTOMFIELD3_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/Contact.CustomField4__c';
import CUSTOMFIELD5_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/Contact.CustomField5__c';
import CUSTOMFIELD6_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/Contact.CustomField6__c';
import CUSTOMFIELD7_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/Contact.CustomField7__c';
import CUSTOMFIELD8_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/Contact.CustomField8__c';
import CUSTOMFIELD9_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/Contact.CustomField9__c';
import CUSTOMFIELD10_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/Contact.CustomField10__c';
import CUSTOMFIELD11_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/Contact.CustomField11__c';
import CUSTOMFIELD12_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/Contact.CustomField12__c';
import CUSTOMFIELD13_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/Contact.CustomField13__c';
import CUSTOMFIELD14_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/Contact.CustomField14__c';
import CUSTOMFIELD15_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/Contact.CustomField15__c';

export default class ContactEditForm extends LightningElement {
    @api recordId;
    @api objectApiName;

    lastNameField = LASTNAME_FIELD;
    firstNameField = FIRSTNAME_FIELD;
    accountField = ACCOUNT_FIELD;
    titleField = TITLE_FIELD;
    phoneField = PHONE_FIELD;
    emailField = EMAIL_FIELD;
    custom1Field = CUSTOMFIELD1_FIELD;
    custom2Field = CUSTOMFIELD2_FIELD;
    custom3Field = CUSTOMFIELD3_FIELD;
    custom4Field = CUSTOMFIELD4_FIELD;
    custom5Field = CUSTOMFIELD5_FIELD;
    custom6Field = CUSTOMFIELD6_FIELD;
    custom7Field = CUSTOMFIELD7_FIELD;
    custom8Field = CUSTOMFIELD8_FIELD;
    custom9Field = CUSTOMFIELD9_FIELD;
    custom10Field = CUSTOMFIELD10_FIELD;
    custom11Field = CUSTOMFIELD11_FIELD;
    custom12Field = CUSTOMFIELD12_FIELD;
    custom13Field = CUSTOMFIELD13_FIELD;
    custom14Field = CUSTOMFIELD14_FIELD;
    custom15Field = CUSTOMFIELD15_FIELD;
}
```

Comment: By import, do you mean the schema import statement?

Comment: @rahulgawale yes, i mean the schema import statement

Answer (score 3):

You can use direct field name as mentioned in the [standard documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.data_edit_record):

```html
<template>
    <lightning-record-edit-form
        object-api-name={objectApiName}
        record-id={recordId}>
    <lightning-messages></lightning-messages>
    <div class="slds-grid">
        <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-2">
            <lightning-input-field field-name="Name"></lightning-input-field>
            <lightning-input-field field-name="Title"></lightning-input-field>
        </div>
        <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-2">
            <lightning-input-field field-name="Phone"></lightning-input-field>
            <lightning-input-field field-name="Email"></lightning-input-field>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="slds-m-top_medium">
        <lightning-button type="submit" variant="brand" label="Edit Contact"></lightning-button>
    </div>
</template>
```

Also its not mandatory to import fields for other use cases like [getRecord](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/reference_wire_adapters_record). You can use as below:

```js
@wire(getRecord, { recordId: '001456789012345678', fields: ['Account.Name','Account. Industry'], optionalFields: ['Account.Phone','Account.Owner.Name'] })
account;
```

### Understanding fields reference imports:

In [this documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.data_wire_service_about), salesforce says that

> This code is almost identical, but it uses a string to identify the
> Account.Name field. This code doesn’t get the benefits that you get
> from importing a reference to the field.

However, I did not find any documentation explicitly mentioning the advantages or disadvantages of importing field Vs string notation. Note that I have given reference debug below:

```js
import ACCOUNT_NAME_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/Account.Name';

---- code ----

    connectedCallback() {
        console.log('ACCOUNT_NAME_FIELD => ', ACCOUNT_NAME_FIELD);
    }
```

If you notice the console, it is almost identical to string notation and we cannot really understand what could be possible advantages (apart from compile time field name check):

[image]

Comment: The obvious advantage: compile time checking that the field exists in the object model. Great for catching typos earlier.

Comment: @PhilW Yup, right. I mean apart from that - added in answer :)
Thanks for suggestion

Comment: @salesforce-sas This looks much better than my current implementation. Thanks for your recommendation and references.